# how to add transitions to a simple slide show in html

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code for a slide show and i need help adding a transition effect from picture to picture. 
If any one has anything that would be great!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var image1 = new Image()
        image1.src = "images/house 2.jpg"
        var image2 = new Image()
        image2.src = "images/desk.jpg"
        var image3 = new Image ()
        image3.src = "images/car.jpg"
        var image4 = new Image ()
        image4.src = "images/life.jpg"
    </script>
<p><img src="images/house.jpg" width="1100px" height="300" name="slide" style="margin-left: 75px; margin-top: 10px;" /></p>

     <script type="text/javascript">
                var step=1;
                function slideit()
                {
                    document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
                    if(step<4)
                        step++;
                    else
                        step=1;
                    setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
                }
                slideit();
            </script>
```

Comment: Why that `eval()` there?

Comment: isnt that whats supposed to go there @MelanciaUK

Comment: This question is too broad and has multitude of tutorials online. You need to research before asking

Comment: If you could let us know what are you planning to use, like jQuery, CSS3, etc, it would be easier to help you out.

Comment: im planning on using javascript @MelanciaUK

Comment: I gave you a generic answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use jQuery and CSS3, this tutorial can help you:

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/sliding/